# How to add a <href> link on the wordpress website using the appointment theme?

Tags: wordpress, appointment

I am developing a Wordpress website using the [appointment theme](https://demo.webriti.com/?theme=Appointment), which is developed by Webriti.

In the demo website, the carousel(slider) works fine and by clicking on the "read more" button, you can be directed to another related webpage. However, when I used this theme, I find out that by creating a slider using "featured images" (I was told to do this by https://help.webriti.com/themes/appointment/how-to-set-up-slider-in-appointment-theme/).

I do not know how to but a  link in the pictures. Thus the slider I created can only contain images, but clicking on those images, there is no link to other referred pages that I want the visitors to see. (e.g, I want the customer to click on a "product" images in the slider and they can actually visit the "products" page. But right now there are just the images and no responses when you click on it.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You don't want to add a read more button link and add the link on the image itself?

Comment: I tried that, but it seems that I can not add links to the carousel in the front page. I don't know if it is the appointment theme that forbide this or something.

Answer (score 1):

This will work 100%

```
<?php
$featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
$featuredPosts->query('showposts=5&cat=3');
while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>
  $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($productPost->ID)); 
<a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"> 

get_the_content();   
or 
<img src="<?php echo$feat_image ?> class="" alt="">

</a>

<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```